# Parser for simple programming language

Tags: java, parsing

I'm writing a basic LL(1) parser in java, but my parser class is quickly getting out of hand and becoming huge. [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) even calls it a "God class" and says that it has "Too many methods." Is there a way that I can refactor this class?

```
public class Parser {
    private static final APValueNum NEGATIVE_ONE = new APValueNum(
            new BigDecimal("-1"));
    LinkedList<Token> tokens = new LinkedList<>();
    Token lookahead;

    public Parser(final List<Token> tokens) {
        this.tokens.addAll(tokens);
        if (tokens.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ParserException("Cannot parse an empty file!");
        }
    }

    private void nextToken() {
        try {
            tokens.pop();
        } catch (final NoSuchElementException e) {
            throw new ParserException("Ran out of characters!", e);
        }
        // at the end of input we return an epsilon token
        if (tokens.isEmpty()) {
            lookahead = new Token(TokenType.EOF, "<EOF>");
        } else {
            lookahead = tokens.getFirst();
        }
    }

    public List<ExpressionNode> parse(final Context context) {

        final List<ExpressionNode> expressions = new ArrayList<>();

        lookahead = tokens.getFirst();

        while (lookahead.getType() != TokenType.EOF) {
            expressions.add(statement(context));
        }
        return expressions;
    }

    private ExpressionNode statement(final Context context) {
        final ExpressionNode.VariableNode expr = identifier();
        nextToken();
        if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.EQUAL) {
            final ExpressionNode assignment = assignment(context, expr);
            return assignment;
        } else if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.IDENTIFIER) {
            // we have a parameter
            nextToken();
            if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.IDENTIFIER
                    || lookahead.getType() == TokenType.EQUAL) {
                final List<VariableNode> variables = new ArrayList<>();
                while (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.IDENTIFIER) {
                    variables.add(identifier());
                    nextToken();
                }
                if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.EQUAL) {
                    nextToken();
                    final ExpressionNode expression = expression(context);
                    final Function function = new Function(expr.getName(),
                            variables, expression);
                    context.putFunction(expr.getName(), function);
                    nextToken();
                    return ExpressionNode.VOID;
                } else {
                    throw new ParserException(
                            "Expected parameter list or equal (function def)");
                }
            } else {
                throw new ParserException("Expected EQUAL");
            }
        } else if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.OPEN_PARENS) {
            final ExpressionNode node = functionParameters(context, expr);
            nextToken();
            return node;
        } else {
            throw new ParserException(
                    "Non function call, assignment, or function def statement");
        }

    }

    private ExpressionNode assignment(final Context context,
            final ExpressionNode.VariableNode expr) {
        nextToken();
        final ExpressionNode assigned = expression(context);
        final ExpressionNode assignment = new ExpressionNode.AssignmentNode(
                expr, assigned);
        if (lookahead.getType() != TokenType.SEMI) {
            throw new ParserException("Expected semicolon, got "
                    + lookahead.getText());
        }
        nextToken();
        return assignment;
    }

    private ExpressionNode expression(final Context context) {
        if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.IF) {
            return ifExpr(context);
        }

        final ExpressionNode expr = signedTerm(context);
        return lowOp(expr, context);
    }

    private ExpressionNode ifExpr(final Context context) {
        assert lookahead.getType() == TokenType.IF;
        nextToken();
        final ExpressionNode ifExpr = expression(context);
        final ExpressionNode thenExpr = expression(context);
        if (lookahead.getType() != TokenType.ELSE) {
            throw new ParserException("Needs else after if, was " + lookahead);
        }
        nextToken();
        final ExpressionNode elseExpr = expression(context);
        return new ExpressionNode.IfNode(ifExpr, thenExpr, elseExpr);
    }

    /*
     * Lower level precedence operations: +, -, ||
     */
    private ExpressionNode lowOp(final ExpressionNode expr,
            final Context context) {
        if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.PLUSMINUS) {
            // sum_op -> PLUSMINUS term sum_op
            ExpressionNode sum;
            final boolean positive = lookahead.getText().equals("+");
            nextToken();
            final ExpressionNode t = signedTerm(context);
            if (positive) {
                sum = new ExpressionNode.AdditionNode(expr, t);
            } else {
                sum = new ExpressionNode.SubtractionNode(expr, t);
            }

            return lowOp(sum, context);
        } else if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.OR) {
            nextToken();
            return lowOp(new ExpressionNode.OrNode(expr, term(context)),
                    context);
        } else if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.LESS_THAN) {
            nextToken();
            return lowOp(new ExpressionNode.LessThanNode(expr, term(context)),
                    context);
        } else if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.GREATER_THAN) {
            nextToken();
            return lowOp(
                    new ExpressionNode.GreaterThanNode(expr, term(context)),
                    context);
        } else if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.LESS_THAN_EQUAL) {
            nextToken();
            return lowOp(new ExpressionNode.LessThanEqualNode(expr,
                    term(context)), context);
        } else if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL) {
            nextToken();
            return lowOp(new ExpressionNode.GreaterThanEqualNode(expr,
                    term(context)), context);
        } else {
            // sum_op -> EPSILON
            return expr;
        }
    }

    private ExpressionNode term(final Context context) {
        // term -> factor term_op
        return highOp(factor(context), context);
    }

    /*
     * High precedence operations: *, /, &&
     */
    private ExpressionNode highOp(final ExpressionNode expr,
            final Context context) {
        if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.MULDIV) {
            // term_op -> MULTDIV factor term_op
            ExpressionNode prod;

            final boolean positive = lookahead.getText().equals("*");
            nextToken();
            final ExpressionNode f = signedFactor(context);

            if (positive) {
                prod = new ExpressionNode.MultiplicationNode(expr, f);
            } else {
                prod = new ExpressionNode.DivisionNode(expr, f);
            }

            return highOp(prod, context);
        } else if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.AND) {
            nextToken();
            return highOp(new ExpressionNode.AndNode(expr, value(context)),
                    context);
        } else {
            // term_op -> EPSILON
            return expr;
        }

    }

    private ExpressionNode signedFactor(final Context context) {
        if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.PLUSMINUS) {
            final boolean positive = lookahead.getText().equals("+");
            nextToken();
            final ExpressionNode t = factor(context);
            if (positive) {
                return t;
            } else {
                return new ExpressionNode.ConstantNode(
                        ((APValueNum) t.getValue(context)).callMethod(
                                Methods.MULTIPLY, NEGATIVE_ONE));
            }
        } else {
            // signed_factor -> factor
            return factor(context);
        }
    }

    private ExpressionNode factor(final Context context) {
        // factor -> argument factor_op
        return factorOp(argument(context), context);
    }

    private ExpressionNode factorOp(final ExpressionNode expression,
            final Context context) {
        if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.RAISED) {
            // factor_op -> RAISED expression
            nextToken();
            final ExpressionNode exponent = signedFactor(context);
            return new ExpressionNode.ExponentiationNode(expression, exponent);

        } else {
            // factor_op -> EPSILON
            return expression;
        }
    }

    private ExpressionNode argument(final Context context) {
        if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.OPEN_PARENS) {
            // argument -> OPEN_BRACKET sum CLOSE_BRACKET
            nextToken();
            final ExpressionNode node = expression(context);

            if (lookahead.getType() != TokenType.CLOSE_PARENS) {
                throw new ParserException("Closing brackets expected and "
                        + lookahead.getText() + " found instead");
            }

            nextToken();
            return node;
        } else {
            // argument -> value
            return value(context);
        }
    }

    private ExpressionNode signedTerm(final Context context) {
        if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.PLUSMINUS) {
            // signed_term -> PLUSMINUS term
            final boolean positive = lookahead.getText().equals("+");
            nextToken();
            final ExpressionNode t = term(context);
            if (positive) {
                return t;
            } else {
                return new ExpressionNode.ConstantNode(t.getValue(context)
                        .callMethod(Methods.MULTIPLY, NEGATIVE_ONE));
            }
        } else {
            // signed_term -> term
            return term(context);
        }
    }

    private ExpressionNode value(final Context context) {
        if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.NUMBER) {
            final ExpressionNode.ConstantNode expr = new ExpressionNode.ConstantNode(
                    new APValueNum(new BigDecimal(lookahead.getText())));
            nextToken();
            return expr;
        } else if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.BOOLEAN) {
            final ExpressionNode.ConstantNode expr = new ExpressionNode.ConstantNode(
                    new APValueBool(Boolean.parseBoolean(lookahead.getText())));
            nextToken();
            return expr;
        }

        else if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.IDENTIFIER) {

            final ExpressionNode.VariableNode expr = identifier();
            nextToken();
            if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.OPEN_PARENS) {
                return functionParameters(context, expr);
            }
            return expr;
        } else {
            throw new ParserException("Unexpected token " + lookahead
                    + " found");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param expr
     * @return
     */
    private ExpressionNode functionParameters(final Context context,
            final ExpressionNode.VariableNode expr) {
        final List<ExpressionNode> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
        nextToken();
        if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.CLOSE_PARENS) {
            // No params
            final ExpressionNode.FunctionCallNode node = new ExpressionNode.FunctionCallNode(
                    expr, parameters);
            nextToken();
            return node;
        }

        parameters.add(expression(context));
        if (lookahead.getType() == TokenType.CLOSE_PARENS) {
            // One parameter
            final ExpressionNode.FunctionCallNode node = new ExpressionNode.FunctionCallNode(
                    expr, parameters);
            nextToken();
            return node;
        }

        while (lookahead.getType() != TokenType.CLOSE_PARENS) {
            if (lookahead.getType() != TokenType.COMMA) {
                throw new ParserException("Expected comma, got " + lookahead);
            }
            nextToken();
            parameters.add(expression(context));
        }
        nextToken();

        return new ExpressionNode.FunctionCallNode(expr, parameters);
    }

    private ExpressionNode.VariableNode identifier() {
        return new ExpressionNode.VariableNode(lookahead.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems fine to me. I wouldn't refactor it just because some robot with no taste says so.

Comment: Yes, but if this file grows even bigger, should I just keep it the same way? I'm not sure, but I feel like there should be some point when it should change.

Comment: Have you considered switching to a parser generator? ANTLR is a personal favorite of mine.

Comment: I've used it before, but I'm just doing this for learning purposes. But ANTLR is pretty great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I look at this code, I find an immediate criticism that may help.  You name many of your functions as nouns, e.g.

```
private ExpressionNode statement(final Context context) {
private ExpressionNode assignment(final Context context,
        final ExpressionNode.VariableNode expr) {
private ExpressionNode expression(final Context context) {
private ExpressionNode ifExpr(final Context context) {
```

Are you sure that these should be functions?  If you are naming a bunch of nouns, maybe these should be classes, each of which could have its own `parse` or `getNext` method.  This is even true of

```
private void nextToken() {
```

But the solution is probably different.  Perhaps simply rename that to `getNextLookahead()`.  Alternately, you could make a new `TokenStream` class with a `getNext` function, or a higher level `ExpressionNode` class like `Package`, `Program`, or `File` with a `parse` method.

Of course, if you follow this advice, you will end up with a much larger number of small classes that basically exist to wrap the `parse` method in each.  You will probably have to pass your `Parser` to each the way that you already pass a `Context`.